# Scrollview not working in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiscrollview

I have scrollview in my xib. I have added it as subview of view. And I have added 2 labels in scrollview one is at top part and anotherone is at bootom. I have set:

```
scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
```

And also set size of scrollview to 800 from xib.

But though scroll is not working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: have you joined delegate of scrollView?

Comment: try adding scrollEnabled to YES...

Comment: yes I have set both ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vivek if you cannot scroll the view even after setting **contentSize** properly then you have to uncheck **"Use AutoLayout"**. You can uncheck it from interface builder.

Comment: yes its worked....and can you help me on this please.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138648/last-row-of-table-not-loaded

Comment: Sure let me check and please accept my answer. Even you can directly ask in our chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43424/coders-diary